# Hibernate Search / Lucene returning null elements when result is one record

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am facing a strange issue here with Hibernate Search and Lucene. I believe this problem is kinda simple: when I'm searching something that returns more than one record, everything works fine. When I'm searching something that return only one record, then the entity elements are all null, but when I call the `toString()` method, everything is there.

My Entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Blob;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Analyze;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Store;

@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "vw_colaborador", schema = "col")
public class Colaborador implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 886370076152195975L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "matricula", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    private String matricula;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "nome", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "email", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "foto", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Blob foto;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "login", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String login;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "ramal", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String ramal;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "hierarquia_ua", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String ua;

    @Column(name = "situacao_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long situacaoId;

    @Column(name = "situacao", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String situacao;

    @Column(name = "vinculo_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long vinculoId;

    @Column(name = "vinculo", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String vinculo;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "diretoria", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String diretoria;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "sigla_diretoria", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String siglaDiretoria;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "sala", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String sala;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "predio", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String predio;

    //... getters and setters ommited

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Colaborador [id=" + id + ", matricula=" + matricula + ", nome=" + nome + ", email=" + email + ", foto=" + foto + ", login=" + login + ", ramal=" + ramal + ", ua="
        + ua + ", situacaoId=" + situacaoId + ", situacao=" + situacao + ", vinculoId=" + vinculoId + ", vinculo=" + vinculo + ", diretoria=" + diretoria
        + ", siglaDiretoria=" + siglaDiretoria + ", sala=" + sala + ", predio=" + predio + "]";
    }
}
```

And my DAO, where I search with Hibernate Search...

ColaboradorDAO (managed by Spring)

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Sort;
import org.apache.lucene.search.SortField;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search;
import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("colaboradorDAO")
public class ColaboradorDAO extends AbstractDAO<Colaborador, Long> {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ColaboradorDAO.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Colaborador> filtrar(Object termo) throws DAOException {
    try {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEm.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Colaborador.class).get();

        Query query = qb.keyword()
            .onFields("matricula", "nome", "email", "login", "ramal", "ua", "diretoria", "siglaDiretoria", "sala", "predio")
            .matching(termo)
            .createQuery();

        FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(query);
        Sort sortField = new Sort(new SortField("nome", SortField.STRING));
        fullTextQuery.setSort(sortField);
        return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao filtrar colaboradores com termo: " + termo, e);
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
    }

    public void indexar() throws DAOException {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

        try {
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Erro ao criar indice de busca dos colaboradores", e);
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the `filtrar(String termo)` method, it works like a charm with no errors and no exceptions. But when I the result of the query is only one record, then the `Colaborador` entity is instantiated but all elements are `null`.

Example:

```
@Test
public void testColaborador() {
    try {
        List<Colaborador> listColaborador = this.colaboradorService.filtrar("060091");
        for (Colaborador c : listColaborador) {
            System.out.println(c.getNome());
        }
    }
    catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
null
```

If I change the line: `System.out.println(c.getNome());` to `System.out.println(c.toString());` then, works great for printing out all elements.

I am using:

- Hibernate Search 4.3.0.Final;
- Hibernate Core 4.2.2.Final;
- Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE;
- Lucene 3.6.2;

Updating my question:

I've upgraded Hibernate Search version to 4.4.0.Alpha1 and the error still persist. I also realized that my entity is related with "lazy load". When I inspect my entity, all properties are null, but there is another property called `JavassistLazyInitializer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, problem solved! I can't use the `final` keyword for methods getters and setters on the entity. When I annotated the getters instead the `private` fields, like @Sanne said, this error message shows on console:

```
ERROR PojoEntityTuplizer:201 - HHH000112: Getters of lazy classes cannot be final
```

Then I removed all final keywords of my entity `Colaborador` and works! So, I changed back the annotations on private fields, and it still working!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does you code not just imply that *c.getNome()* is *null*? Have you checked your data? Is that the case? Given that c.toString() works you get for sure an entity back. Or are you saying that in the *toString* representation there is a value for *nome*?

Comment: The method `c.getNome()` and all other get methods are returning `null`. For me, this is a bizarre error because the `toString()` method is correctly filled with correct data. As I say, this only happens when one record is returned.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Search uses a different strategy when only one entity has to be initialized, which indeed might trigger some weirdness in Javassist proxies. Could you try to annotate the getters instead of the private fields?

Comment: @Sanne, thank you so much! Well your answer is almost right. Indeed, is not the location of the annotations, but the keyword `final` on `getters` and `setters`! I'm so stupid! I removed all `final` keyword and, gotcha! Works like a charm! Thanks!